# RestSharp: how to XmlDeserializer this response?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Notice there are extra repositories and data tags before the list of repositories-item. I used the `NexusRepo` class to model `repositories-item`, but getting this error:

```
Exception caught: System.ApplicationException: Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.HandleListDerivative(XElement root, String propName, Type type)
   at RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.Deserialize[T](IRestResponse response)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest request, IRestResponse raw)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

[image]

```
public List<NexusRepo> GetAllRepos()    
{
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    //RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/repositories", Method.GET);
    request.Resource = "/repositories";
    request.RootElement = "NexusRepo";

    return this.restSharpAPI.Execute<List<NexusRepo>>(this.client, request);

}

public class NexusRepo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public string resourceURI { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s = "name=" + name + "format=" + format + "resourceURI=" + resourceURI;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `NexusRepo` class name differs from `repositories-item` node name. You may add `[DeserializeAs]` attribute to resolve it:

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "repositories-item")]
public class NexusRepo
```

Or you may rename class or node to satisfy one of the following conditions:

> When searching data for a matching element, the default XML
>   deserializer will look for elements and attributes in the following
>   order:
>
> - Element with exact name match
> - Element with name matching lower-cased property name
> - Element with name matching camel-cased property name
> - Element with underscores and dashes removed from name
> - Attribute with exact name match
> - Attribute with name matching lower-cased property name
> - Attribute with name matching camel-cased property name
> - Attribute with underscores and dashes removed from name

As specified in [official docs](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization).

Comment: I tried to add the attribute and rename the class as RepositoriesItem, still ended with the same error as before. Is there a way to specify the node where it start to search, or shall I use a nested class to model this?

Comment: It should work without nested class (if your XML is valid), let's try to remove `request.RootElement = "NexusRepo";` statement at all. Another option is to generate exact C# representation of your XML and use it as example: http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 0):

It works after I:

1. Added the attribute
2. Add using RestSharp.Deserializers;
3. Comment out RootElement line below.

   //request.RootElement = "NexusRepo";